# Spree Commerce 2.0 Stable Not Sending Copy of Confirmation Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, e-commerce, spree

I have been unable to get Spree to send a copy of an order confirmation email after an order is placed.  The customer gets the order confirmation however.  I can intercept the order confirmation email as well.  I have added my email in the Spree Admin "Send Copy of all mails to", as well as having tried adding `config.mail_bcc = "contact@mydomain.com"` in the `config/initializers/spree.rb`.  I checked the params when I update the Admin, and it does correctly send the `mail_bcc = 'contact@mydomain.com'`.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Spree 2.0 has some e-mail settings in the admin area which are a bit problematic.  I generally recommend setting:

```
# config/initializers/spree.rb
Spree.config do |config|
  config.override_actionmailer_config = false
end
```

This will allow you to use the default ActionMailer configuration.  Without this setting, Spree will use its own code to handle mail configuration through the admin area.

For more information see:

[Spree Deployment Tips](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deployment_tips.html)

[Example ActionMailer Configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration)

Comment: Alright, I have set the ActionMailer override to false as you suggested, and also set ActionMailer::Base.default bcc: 'contact@mydomain.com', still no love.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Which delivery method are you using?

Comment: What do you mean  by delivery method?

Comment: Mail needs to go somewhere.  Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration  The delivery method specified if it's using sendmail, smtp, or some other method of delivering the mail.

Comment: Try testing out your SMTP from the Rails console using instructions like this: https://gist.github.com/tansengming/101141  You most likely have a misconfiguration in your mail settings somewhere.